# npm can't find npm-debug.log file when initializing npm install (Angular 2-CLI)

Tags: angular, npm, npm-debug

When installing npm package for my new Angular 2 project, I am getting below issue.

```
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\CR_Automation_UI_POC\POC\npm-debug.log
```

So, the issue is that npm is not able to find npm-debug.log file, but it is already present in folder. How to resolve this issue?

This screen shot of console window of Visual Studio Code looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gBNK.png)

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the package.json as well

Comment: I have shared package.json file. Sorry, if it is not coming in proper way.

Comment: can you try deleting your node_modules folder and try running npm install again? I don`t see a relevant dependency which might be relevant to the error.

Comment: I tried that multiple times, but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the error the CLI throws is caused by a missing debug.log file.

It's telling you to include it if you choose to submit any support request to the authors of the npm package you are trying to install, which is `node-forge`, so I'm guessing the error is probably there. Can you include the .log file?

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that the npm-debug.log file is not the issue. The issue is the failure of installing node-forge.

Comment: yes, I agree with @FilipBarakovski. Can you share your npm-debug.log file also? the error related to node-forge shouldn`t come as it has not been specified in package.json.